# Removing HTML without escaping

Tags: php, search, preg-replace, str-replace, preg-replace-callback

```
<div class="item itemask" ><div class="tophead"><div class="itemnumber"></div><a class="article" href=""></a> </div><div class="bottomhead"> points by <a class="userlink" rel=""></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;  ago&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=">discuss</a></div></div>
```

How can PHP remove all instances of the above snippet in a page without requiring escaping the above string. Or, how can I easily get the escape-string of the above in order to plug into a preg_replace to remove it.

I need to run PHP on the server against a bunch of htm files. It must be done on the server-side in one operation.

Comment: What did you try??

Comment: I don't know what to escape.. so I didn't try. I need to strip this multiple times out of a few thousand pages.

Comment: Isn't there an online calculator to create PHP escape strings? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could escape your search string with [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

> > ```
> > string preg_quote ( string $str [, string $delimiter = NULL ] )
> > ```
>
> `preg_quote()` takes **str** and puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax. This is useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some text and the string may contain special regex characters.
>
> The special regular expression characters are: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

Comment: \<div class\="item itemask" \>\<div class\="tophead"\>\<div class\="itemnumber"\>\<\/div\>\<a class\="article" href\=""\>\<\/a\> \<\/div\>\<div class\="bottomhead"\> points by \<a class\="userlink" rel\=""\>\<\/a\>&nbsp;&nbsp;  ago&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\<a href\="http\:\/\/news\.ycombinator\.com\/item\?id\="\>discuss\<\/a\>\<\/div\>\<\/div\>

Comment: that's what I got using preg_quote($keywords, '/') -- so looks right to me. Thanks.